# Resizing the background image using different screen

Tags: ionic2

I have a problem because my backgound image not resized in different screen sizes. My code is like this:

**home.scss**

```
.home {
background: url("../../img/my_image.png") no-repeat center center fixed; 
}
```

Somebody know how can I solve it?
Thanks in advance.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using background-size as cover or 100%.

.home {
background: url("../../img/my_image.png") no-repeat center center/**cover** fixed; 
}